# Hash not being recognized

Tags: ruby, hash

I read a way to create a hash, which is demonstrated below. When I try to add a movie that already exists, ruby doesn't return the right string. If I put a regular hash (e.g `movies` = `{Pirates: 3, James_Bond: 4}`), it returns correctly. Could anyone explain why this is the case?

```
movie = %w(Pirates James_Bond Finding_Nemo)
rating = [4, 3, 5]
movies = Hash[movie.zip(rating)]
puts "What would you like to do?"
choice = gets.chomp
case choice
  when "add"
    puts "What title would you like to add?"
    title = gets.chomp
    if movies[title.to_sym].nil?
      puts "What is the rating of this movie?"
      rating = gets.chomp
      movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
    else
      puts "Movie already exists."
    end
end
```

Comment: Why don't you use `{Pirates: 3, James_Bond: 4, ...}`? It looks much cleaner to me.

Comment: I probably will end up using that method. But since I'm just beginning to learn this stuff, I'd like to understand why and how the code works. Plus, it's always good to have alternatives!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There it is.

```
movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
```

`%w` operator creates array of strings, not symbols. You should do this:

```
movies[title.to_s] = rating.to_i
```

Or you can create array of symbols using `%i` operator. Choose the operator you really want (thanks @muistooshort)

```
%w(Pirates James_Bond Finding_Nemo) # => ["Pirates", "James_Bond", "Finding_Nemo"]
%i(Pirates James_Bond Finding_Nemo) # => [:Pirates, :James_Bond, :Finding_Nemo]
```

Comment: Or use `%i`/`%I` if you're in Ruby2 land.

Comment: +1 for `%i`, I didn't know about that. You can also do `movies = %w(Pirates Jame_bond Finding_Nemo).map(&:to_sym)` if you must have symbols.

Comment: @muistooshort: yeah, right. I was looking it up. because never ever actually used it. Who creates symbol arrays like this? You don't get special syntax highlighting (which one of the largest benefits of symbols for me)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the explanation and demonstration!

Comment: @siopao - If this answered your question, please consider giving it the check-mark.